# tinyMCE automatically parses links

Tags: php, tinymce

I use tinyMCE like:

```
$usetinymce="tinyMCE.init({
    entity_encoding : \"raw\",
    elements : \"text,newstext\",
    mode : \"exact\",
    theme: \"advanced\",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : \"bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,\"
    + \"justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,\"
    + \"bullist,numlist,outdent,indent\",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : \"link,unlink,anchor,image,separator,\"
    +\"undo,redo,cleanup,code,separator,sub,sup,charmap\",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : \"\"

    });";
```

If I insert a link the it appears like:
http://www.111.gr/\">www.111.gr/

How is this extra \ added? I also did a print_r($_POST) and still appears.

any help

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding `convert_urls : false` to your init function.

It would help if you posted the version of TinyMCE you are using.

Comment: This worked for me, where tinyMCE automatically replaces localhost to ../, thanks for the tip.